# jQuery: reducing repaints

Tags: jquery, css, animation, clone, repaint

I need to optimize an image gallery slider since a lot of browsers have a hard time dealing with the animations.

Please consider the following example:

```
var $div1 = $('#div1'),
$div2 = $('#div2'),
$div3 = $('#div3'),
left = 0;

function animate() {
  left -= 10;
  $div1.css({
    left: left + 'px',
    width: 1000 - left + 'px'
  });
  $div2.css( 'left', left - 10 + 'px' );
  $div3.css( 'left', left - 40 + 'px' );
}

setInterval( animate, 20 );
```

This, of course, puts an immense pressure on a lot of browsers and it requires three repaints every 20 ms!

Is there any way to clone the three div's, work on them off-line and them replace ALL of them at once and thereby reduce the amount of repaints to one?

If you have other suggestions, **please** feel free to share them.

Thanks!

Comment: Erm... what's wrong with jQuery's very own `animate()`?

Comment: Would I just set animate on each of them and let them run for 20 ms?

Comment: I've just converted to animate. It's still choppy, so I didn't gain anything unfortunately.

Comment: Your code is liable to be a similar speed to the jQuery internal, the big problem is the atrocious JS engines in browsers other than Chrome.

Comment: Please give an example page with markup, preferably on http://jsfiddle.com or http://jsbin.com

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can make this process more resource-efficient.

Idea 1: 20ms works out to 50 FPS. Your average Hollywood film runs at 24-30 FPS (I forget the exact frame rate). Try an interval of 33 - 40ms.

Idea 2: Use absolute positioning where possible to minimize the amount of reflowing required for the rest of the document.

Idea 3: Consolidate all of your animations into a single timer. I imagine most good frameworks will take care of this for you.

Ultimately, either you or your framework will be iteratively setting the CSS properties for each selector, so I think you will realize your gains by looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Idea1: I could increase the speed, but it's still choppy in most browsers. Idea2: I forgot to say the divs are all absolutely positioned. Idea3: Single timer? I'm not sure I follow. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Here's the output from MozAfterPaint: http://pastebin.com/K3N0MZCW when doing the slide.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - I think I misunderstood part of your question. On idea 1, I actually meant to slow down the repaints from 50 times per second to 25-30. But your MozAfterPaint output indicates that you're still able to run faster than that.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of SpeedTracer. After the DOM click (where the animation starts) you can see 100 % repaints taking more than 20 ms. I guess that's the problem. That the repaints take longer than the interval itself. http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/7067/screenshot20100916at085.png

Comment: Maybe this can explain a potential bottle neck? http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/4701/screenshot20100916at090.png

Comment: I guess it's hard to say much more at this point without seeing an example of the page. Perhaps this SO thread can be of some help, as he was apparently trying to achieve something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761379/jquery-animations-are-choppy-and-stutter-in-firefox

Comment: @Morten: In animation on computers in general, it is important not to attempt to redraw more frames per second than can be coped with.  When you see the FPS rate on a game, that is how many it can achieve - not the target.  The policy is usually to do as many updates as you can per second, up to a point where more are unnecessary, rather than set an interval speed and hope it copes.